# How is "low quality" flagged?

Tags: support, reviews, flagging

[How to explain atheism in a world where religious miracles are commonplace and spirits visit earth](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/44366/how-to-explain-atheism-in-a-world-where-religious-miracles-are-commonplace-and-s/44417#44417)

This appeared in the queue "because of length and content". Why? It wasn't a super-short post by a newish user. What about it distingishes it from any other post? Are there keywords? Otherwise, I have to think it was flagged manually somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this was flagged manually as Not an Answer, and entered the moderator flag queue and the Low Quality Posts queue. The community dealt with it before a diamond moderator did, and, for the record, it was automatically marked as "[disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275/274942)" after going through the review queue.

Comment: So, "not an answer" goes to a different queue, I see. I thought they all go to "close".

Comment: @JDługosz No, only (some) questions go to the close queue.